# WebApi return custom ServiceResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have normal WebApi controller that with methods:

```
public class ModelController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Model> Get()
    {
        return service.Get();
    }

    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return service.Get(id);
    }

    public void Post([FromBody]MyViewModel value)
    {
        return service.Save(value);
    }

    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]MyViewModel value)
    {
        return service.Save(value);
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        return service.Delete(value);
    }
}
```

I want to wrap return results in to custom object ServiceResult

```
public class ServiceResult<T>
{
    public bool IsError{ get; set; }
    public T ObjectModel {get; set}
}
```

I want to change the return type on all my controller methods to ServiceResult
Here is an example:

```
public ServiceResult Post([FromBody]MyViewModel value)
{
    service.Save(value);
    //getting error here:
    return new ServiceResult() { IsError= true, ObjectModel = value };
}
```

But getting the error

> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for
>   content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
>
> Type 'Models.View.MyViewModel' with
>   data contract name
>   'MyViewModel://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyViewModel'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any
>   types not known statically to the list of known types - for example,
>   by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the
>   list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

Do you have any idea how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Your ServiceResult object requires a type argument, Try this

```
return new ServiceResult<MyViewModel>() { IsError= true, ObjectModel = value };
```